# How to Extract A RAR file selected by dialogbox

Tags: c#, dialog, extract, rar

I have a code in C# to extract a zip file to a specific folder.
I want to extract a RAR file from that code.
I tried some other things like 7-zip, IO.Compression but it was not suitable for me.
here is the code which I used to extract the zip file.

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(openFileDialog1.FileName, "TestFolder"); 
                MessageBox.Show("ZIP file extracted successfully!");
            }
```

what I want, is like this.
When a user selects a Zip or RAR file this code extract the respected file in the pre-specified folder.
This is a windows form Application.
Please help. 
Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAR is a different compression format. You should use another library to handle RAR files, since there is nothing built in for `.NET`. For example: http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com

From the official documentation page: "Extract all files from a Rar file to a directory using RarArchive"

```
using (var archive = RarArchive.Open("Test.rar"))
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries.Where(entry => !entry.IsDirectory))
    {
        entry.WriteToDirectory("D:\\temp", new ExtractionOptions()
        {

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Todmmaso Belluzzo thanks my friend. i have a question. did you use rararchve library?

Comment: i am facing errors on                                                                                                         entry.WriteToDirectory("D:\\temp", new ExtractOptions()
                    {
                        ExtractFullPath = true,
                        Overwrite = true
                    });                                                                                                            Extractionoption, extractfullpath and overwrite

Comment: You should really start reading the documentation of that library.